Why Vercel Custom Domain looses CDN? Should I set CDN outside of Vercel?
Why Vercel Custom Domain looses CDN? Should I set CDN outside of Vercel?
% dig mydomain.com
;; ANSWER SECTION:
mydomain.com        300 IN  A   76.76.21.21
% dig mydomain.vercel.app
;; ANSWER SECTION:
mydomain.vercel.app.    947 IN  A   76.76.xx.xx
mydomain.vercel.app.    947 IN  A   76.76.xx.xx


It does not lose the CDN. You are comparing apples to oranges here:

The CDN capability you may be referring to (resolving to the nearest Vercel DC) is unrelated to it resolving to 76.76.21.21 or 76.76.x.x IPs.
76.76.21.21 is an anycast IP. You can read more about it here.
Using cname.vercel-dns.com will resolve to a series of IPs.

Therefore, when you use 76.76.21.21, you are still using the Vercel edge network, but the network layer will "do more work" to arrive at the nearest DC. But if you are using cname.vercel-dns.com, that record has already "unfolded" to the IPs directly when querying cname.vercel-dns.com depending on your location.
I hope this helps.
